# Populate table from backend data [AngularJS + Flask]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask

I know that this might look as a repeat question.

I'm almost 3 days trying to find a solution for this case. Some ppl have already said that I'm supposed to use AJAX. I'm not very used to the front end coding, and it's been really hard to find a solution. I know NOTHING about AJAX, and I'd like to find a solution in ANGULARJS coding as long it is what I've been studying. I really think what I'm trying to do is a simple taks, but as long I'm a full newbie, I'm finding it trully dificult. Here it goes.

I use the code below to "try" to collect the data from a given race (raceId) that's selected from HTML form.

**FLASK BACK END**

```
<!-- language: python3 -->

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') #index
def showDriverList():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/getResult', methods=['POST']) #give the result of a selected raceid
def getResult():
    resultDetail = {
            'finalresult':'finalresult',
            'id':'id'}
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            result = request.form.get('raceId')
            print('-=-='*25, result) #debug
            resdb = db.Races.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(result)})
            resultDetail = {
                'finalresult':resdb['finalresult'],
                'id':str(resdb['_id'])}
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
    print(json.dumps(resultDetail)) #debug
    return json.dumps(resultDetail)
```

**The HTML form code is**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div class="row">
   <form method="POST">
     <label>Select a Race</label>
       <select id='selectBy' class="form-control" name="raceId" ng-model="raceresult" ng-change="selRace()">

        <option ng-repeat="row in rows" value="{{row}}" name="raceId">
            {{row}}
        </option>

       </select>
      </form>
<hr>
  </div>
```

**It's important to say that I'd like the form to be changing a table dynamically.**

```
    <table>
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
      </thead>

       <tbody ng-repeat="item in results">
         <tr>
           <th>{{item}}</th> 

           <td>{{item}}</td>

         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>



<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I also put some example data in the angular code, as long we are unable to access the database. Still, I can assure you that WHEN I submit the form below using

```
<form action='/getResult'>
```

I'm sent to localhost:5000/getResult and the page shows me the right result for the ID selected as a very long JSON text in the browser window.

So, I can get the data, but I'm not finding a way to make it useful for AngularJS to populate the table.

**The Angular code is like this:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.rows = ['row1','row2','row3'];
    //Here goes some example data. Everything is supposed to be retrieved from flask back end
    //The $scope.results is an example of how the data comes from backend
            $scope.results = [{
        'id':'row1',
        'finalresult': [{'name': 'Ayrton Senna', 'position':1 },{'name': 'Nigel Mansell', 'position':2}]},
        {'id':'row2',
        'finalresult': [{'name': 'Ayrton Senna', 'position':1 },{'name': 'Michael Schumacher', 'position':2}]},
        {'id':'row3',
        'finalresult': [{'name': 'Ayrton Senna', 'position':1 },{'name': 'Michael Schumacher', 'position':2}, {'name': 'Nigel Mansell', 'position':3}]}];

    //The $scope.raceresult is how the data was supposed to be get by $scope.selRace().
    //I mean that I'd like this data to be retrieved and displayed in the HTML table by using ng-change
        $scope.raceresult = {'id':'row1',
        'finalresult': [{'name': 'Ayrton Senna', 'position':1 },{'name': 'Nigel Mansell', 'position':2}]}
    //end of example data

    // this is the POST request that front should do to retrieve data from backend.
    $scope.showresult = function(id){ 
          $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/getResult',
            data : "raceid=" + id, // I'm totally UNSURE that is exactly what I wanted to do =/ 
          }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.result = response.data;
            console.log('POST', $scope.result)
          },
          function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
        }

    $scope.selRace = function() {
          $scope.id = $scope.e.value;
          console.log("TEST", $scope.id)
          $scope.showresult($scope.id)
          }
          }
```

I'm not sure I gave you all the info you needed to give me new insights. So I created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmlz/7MhLd/2920/) for trying to make things a little more clear. I don't really want a FINAL ANSWER for this question. All I want are insights of how I could do what I want. I think I may be stuck in a very simple logic that is not going inside my mind.

Comment: Here's a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9xr13dee/ (and note that you are using AJAX: `$http` *is* AJAX)

Comment: @ChrisG Just awesome! I knew it was just a lack of experience! I thank you very very much!